# Why does Reflection's SetValue throw an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to copy some property values from one object to another (both objects implement IVenue, but object b needs to have some values removed dynamically). Wanting to avoid a lot of code like:

```
a.Property1 = b.Property1;
a.Property2 = b.Property2;
etc
```

I am attempting to use Reflection to loop the properties and copy across:

```
public VenueContract(TVDData.Interfaces.IVenue v, List<TVDData.APIClientPermittedFields> permittedFields)
{
    PropertyInfo[] Properties = this.GetType().GetProperties( BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in Properties)
    {
        PropertyInfo source = v.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        p.SetValue (p, source.GetValue(v,null),null);
    }
}
```

However I receive the error:

> "Object does not match target type"

Both properties are type int, declared as:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
```

The problem appears to lie in *p.SetValue* as *source.GetValue(v,null)* returns the expected value.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? Feel free to suggest a completely alternative approach if that would be a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first argument on `SetValue` is incorrect - it's try to set the property *on the `PropertyInfo`*.

You probably meant:

```
 p.SetValue(this, source.GetValue(v, null), null);
```

Comment: Mr Skeet, I could kiss you (but I won't).